# MDX maximum of daily average for two dimensions

Tags: mdx, average

I have a cube with `[Serialnumber]` dimension and `[Time]` Dimension. Measure is `Avg CPU Usage`.

I want to somehow formulate an `MDX` Query that

- calculates Avg CPU Usage per Serialnumber and Day
- formulates a measure for max average

Example:

```
day 1   20% 
day 2   60% 
day 3   30%
```

When I look at months in `MDX` Query I want to select a measure which tells me 
60% because in month day 2 was the day with the highest average cpu usage per day.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I is very probably possible - although without seeing your current script we cannot help: all cubes are different so seeing your script will help a lot. If you can model your scenario using the MS AdvWrks cube even better.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: Your date dimension is called Date and has a Day level, which is the one you want to use on your average. You have a dimension called Time, which has multiple measurements, which are assumed to take place at regular intervals, lets say second (such that the average is the arithmetic average. If they are not and you need to calculate time between measurements to calculate a weighted average things are messier.

The query

```
With 
  Member [Measures].[Average] as ( [Time].[Second].Members, [Measures].[CPU] )
  Member [Measures].[Max Average] as Max( Descendants( [Date].CurrentMember, [Date].[Day] ), [Measures].[Average] ) 
Select 
  Descendants( [Date].[2014], [Date].[Months] ) on Rows, 
  [Measures].[Max Average] on Columns 
From [My Cube]
```

should give you the max daily average per month for a given year.

As someone mentioned in a comment to the OP, without further detail about your specific cube structure, there isn't much more than can be done.